# Why doesn't the inline-block element occupy full height in the following example?

Tags: html, css

There is an inline-block element with 100% height and width :

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: red; display: inline-block">Y</div>
```

Why [doesn't this `div` take up whole height, but takes up full width](http://jsfiddle.net/gdyLs/)?

Comment: You need `height: 100%;` set on `html` and `body` for it to take up full height. `inline-block` treats it as inline first (like text), it only takes up 100% height of the content without adding the aforementioned `height` to `html` and `body`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An auto width on a block box [causes it to be as wide as its containing block allows](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth). An auto height, on the other hand, [causes it to only be as tall as its contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#normal-block).

The block box in question is `body`, and by extension, `html`. Neither element has an intrinsic height (even though the initial containing block does), so the height of both elements defaults to `auto`.

The 100% width and height of the inline-block respect the used width and height of its containing block, which in this case is `body`. If you specify any arbitrary height on `body`, or `height: 100%` on both `html, body`, then the inline-block will be adjusted accordingly.

Note that because an inline-block is essentially the same as a block box except laid inline, percentage width and height are calculated the same way as if the element were block-level.

Comment: The div takes full width because its parent, body, is a block-level element by default?

Comment: @user3790069: Correct.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `html` and `body` tags don't take full height.

Unless specified otherwise, block elements take full width, but only as much height as needed - it is only natural, since HTML was originally meant as a way to format text documents. You wouldn't want, say, a paragraph to take the full window height.

You must set their height to `100%` to get it work - stretch them to the window height:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gdyLs/1/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why.

Comment: @TylerH not sure what more explanation you'd want.

Comment: The question is **why** this `inline-block` doesn't take up the whole height of the body. Your answer says, essentially "because it doesn't." While your code does solve the problem, it doesn't do a good job of explaining, and an explanation was the real request.

Comment: Now there is some explanation, but I don't think it needed it.

Answer (score 0):

It takes height of its parent

try:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because a div by default takes full width, unless specified otherwise.

Making it inline-block, just allows it to be inline, but preserving its block nature such as setting width and height, top and bottom margins and paddings.

And the height of every element(not-null) in html markup is same as height of a line.. which can be changed by `line-height` property.

And if you wish it to take all-height, follow the above answers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify height to `html` and `body` then only that `div` will take `100% height`

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why.