# CSS rule resizes iframe width but not height

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an index.html markup as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>...</header>
      <iframe id="pagecontent" src="content.html"></iframe>
      <footer>...</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

To apply styles, I use main.css whose content is as follows:

```
 #pagecontent {
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The width of the iframe is assigned correctly. That is, when I resize the browser window, the width of the iframe is adjusted accordingly. However, the height is always the same. It is about 300px and does not expand to the height of the browser window. I tried this in FF 45 and IE 11.

**Question:** What is the reason for the height not being adjusted in the same way as the width when applied to the iframe?

Comment: iframes by default are `inline` so try `line-height` instead or use `display: block;` Also 100% of what? 100% of whatever contains the iframe so you should wrap iframe in an element and set a height explicitly.

Comment: Neither `line-height` nor `display: block;` help. The result is the same

Comment: The parent element needs to have a defined height otherwise `height: 100%` will not work.

Comment: Please see answer;

Comment: According to the post, when using display: block rule, the corresponding element should behave like a block element. Why do you need another div then?

Comment: Block elements height by default would be `auto` and that will rely on content. Unfortunately, content is treated differently in [replaced elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8018354/2813224) which are img, video, iframe, etc. which will override normal CSS conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You have height set to 100% but 100% of what? It's always the parent of that element so what is the parent's height set to? If it's not set to anything then the browser has nothing to reference.

So you have to give height in `px` here

```
#pagecontent {
    border: none;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

working example : https://jsfiddle.net/uxq4pzc1/

Answer (score 0):

iframes by default are inline so try `line-height` instead or use `display: block` Also 100% of what? 100% of whatever contains the iframe so you should wrap iframe in an element and set a height explicitly.

Whenever I use an iframe, I wrap it in a block level element and set `position: relative`. Then I place `position: absolute` `top:0; bottom:0; right: 0; left: 0;` on the iframe. Whenever you want control over the iframe, use it's parent instead.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24724970/2813224) for details

```css
#pagecontent {
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.box {
  height: 20em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>...</header>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe id="pagecontent" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
  </div>
  <footer>...</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I guess this is the same as I would fix the height of the iframe directly. Regarding 100%, well, the width seems to be computed as 100% of width of the browser window. Why does not it work for the height then?

Comment: It's an inline element but if you want it to behave like a div (like normal) use `display: block` like in this demo. Or `display: inline-block` if you want it to sit side-by-side with other elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#pagecontent {
  border: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>...</header>
  <iframe id="pagecontent" src="content.html"></iframe>
  <footer>...</footer>
</body>

</html>
```